# Java ConcurrentHashMap usage

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to create a Map in java where key and value are as specified :
Key = Object of class DataSourceCredentials

```
public class DataSourceCredentials {
String dataSourceName;
char[] password;
List<String> clusterNodes;
}
```

Value = Object of class DataSourceConnector

```
public class DataSourceConnector {
private static volatile ConcurrentMap<DataSourceCredentials, DataSourceConnector> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<DataSourceCredentials, DataSourceConnector>();
}
```

The equals method of DataSourceCredentials checks for dataSourceName and clusterNodes but not password. This is so since the password of the dataSource can change.

**I have created the below getInstance() method for class DataSourceConnector such that for a single value of DataSourceCredentials only one instance of DataSourceConnector is created and returned.**

```
public static DataSourceConnector getInstance(List<String> clusterNodes, String dataSourceName, char[] password) {
    try {

        DataSourceCredentials dataSource = new DataSourceCredentials(clusterNodes, dataSourceName, password );

        //check if DataSourceConnector already exists then return the same 
        for (DataSourceCredentials dataSourceCredential : map.keySet()) {
            if (dataSourceCredential.equals(dataSource)) {
                if ((password == null && dataSourceCredential.getPassword() == null) || (password != null
                        && dataSourceCredential.getPassword() != null && Arrays.equals(password, dataSourceCredential.getPassword()))) {
                    return map.get(dataSourceCredential);
                }
            }
        }


        DataSourceConnector connector = map.get(dataSource);    

        //if DataSourceConnector has not not been created then create one and return
        if(connector==null)
        {
            DataSourceConnector connector = new DataSourceConnector();
            return accessors.putIfAbsent(dataSource,connector); 
        }
        else  //if DataSourceConnector exists but password has changed/removed/added then create a new connector and return
        {
            synchronized(DataSourceConnector.class)
            {
                for (DataSourceCredentials dataSourceCredential : map.keySet()) {
                    if (dataSourceCredential.equals(dataSource) && ((password == null && dataSourceCredential.getPassword() != null)
                            || (!Arrays.equals(password, dataSourceCredential.getPassword())))) {
                        map.remove(dataSourceCredential);
                        DataSourceConnector connector = new DataSourceConnector();
                        return map.putIfAbsent(dataSource, connector);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (password != null) {
            Arrays.fill(password, '\0');
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Can someone suggest if the above implementation is ok and if there is a better way to do it ?

Comment: Your equals method won't work. You need to override equals and hashcode method in DataSourceCredentials class. Read this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html

Comment: yeah have done that.